# URL Redirect / Rewrite on GKE Gateway and HTTPRoute

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am attempting to set up a gateway on the Google Kubernetes Engine, where I would like to rewrite requests at /api, but I am unable to get it to work.

My Gateway is configured as follows:

```
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: external-http
spec:
  gatewayClassName: gke-l7-global-external-managed
  listeners:
  - name: https
    protocol: HTTPS
    port: 443
    tls:
      mode: Terminate
      options:
        networking.gke.io/pre-shared-certs: "my-certificate-name"
  - name: http
    protocol: HTTP
    port: 80
```

And my HTTPRoute:

```
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: my-route
spec:
  parentRefs:
  - kind: Gateway
    name: external-http
  hostnames:
  - "example.com"
  rules:
  - backendRefs:
    - name: frontend
      port: 80
  - matches:
    - path:
        type: PathPrefix
        value: /api
    filters:
    - type: URLRewrite
      urlRewrite:
        path:
          type: ReplacePrefixMatch
          replacePrefixMatch: /
    backendRefs:
    - name: backend
      port: 80
```

What I want to do is route any requests at /api to my backend application, but I want them to be rewritten to /.

With all this configuration my routes are not getting rewritten and when I look at the events of my HTTPRoute it shows the following error:

`failed: Error GWCER104: HTTPRoute "default/my-route" is misconfigured, err: unsupported filter type: URLRewrite.`

I have followed the guide from google to set up URL redirects, and I don't see what I would be doing differently that would cause this error.
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/deploying-gateways#configure_url_rewrites

According to the google docs the gateway class I am using should support URL Redirects
https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gatewayclass-capabilities?hl=en

My cluster is on version 1.27.2-gke.2100

Why would I be getting an error that URLRewrite is unsupported when in the Google documentation it says it should be?

Comment: What region are your clusters in?  It can take some time for [the updated features](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#autoscaling_profiles) to rollout to all regions.

Comment: My cluster is located in us-central1-a

Comment: @GariSingh were you able to find anything? I really appreciate the help

Comment: @MatthewWeeks were you able to find anything? I have a similar problem!

Comment: @DavidGourde Unfortunately not I had to give up and handle the URL rewriting within my application instead. I think the docs might have changed to say there is more compatibility since I posted this but I have no way to verify

Comment: The docs did not change. I opened a support ticket with Google for a similar issue (UrlRewrite with ReplaceFullPath, here's my SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77225274/gke-gateway-api-httproute-invalid-path-type-replacefullpath-for-urlrewrite). Similar problem, so I'll post the solution here if I get one. Right now, they seem as confused as we are based on the code and doc.

Answer (score 1):

The `URLRewrite` in your `HTTPRoute` on GKE gate based on the error message is not supported. From the same [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gatewayclass-capabilities?hl=en#gatewayclass_capabilities) it shows that the GKE version is not yet supported.

I would like to suggest open [issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) and submit concern as a feature request.

Comment: If it isn't supported then why is there a checkmark next to URL Rewrites for the gateway class I'm using? Is there supposed to be a different way to configure URL rewrites other than in an HTTPRoute? Why would they have the guide on how to do it when it isn't supported? Maybe I just don't understand