# GKE Gateway API, HTTPRoute invalid path type "ReplaceFullPath" for "URLRewrite" filter even though it should work

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, api-gateway

I have a Gateway (Gateway API) on GKE with an HTTPRoute with a setup like this:

```
- matches:
  - path:
      type:
      value: /prefix/health
  backendRefs:
    - name: some-backend
      port: some-port
  filters:
    - type: URLRewrite
      urlRewrite:
        path:
          type: ReplaceFullPath
          replaceFullPath: /ready
```

When I look on the Gateway object, I see this error:

```
Error GWCER104: HTTPRoute "my-httproute"
  is misconfigured, err: invalid path type "ReplaceFullPath" configured for "URLRewrite"
  filter, path type must be "ReplacePrefixMatch".
```

The Gateway Class is `gke-l7-global-external-managed`, which is compatible with those filters according to the doc ([here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gatewayclass-capabilities#gatewayclass_capabilities), look at the bottom next to `urlRewrite.path`).

I followed [the API spec documentation for the filters](https://gateway-api.sigs.k8s.io/references/spec/#gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1beta1.HTTPRouteFilter).

Is there a problem with the way I write it, or is there a problem on the GKE Gateway side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discussed with a solutions engineer from Google and it seems that the problem was their documentation. The Google Gateway API **does not** support the `replaceFullPath` filter on **any** Gateway class.

The documentation has been updated now and only shows replacePrefixMatch (see at [the bottom of this page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/gatewayclass-capabilities#gatewayclass_capabilities)).